# HTML5 local storage - Store and load CSS that has been downloaded once

Tags: javascript, css, html, caching, local-storage

I would like to know if it's possible to do the following: Store CSS and/or JavaScript files using HTML5 local storage, and when a page is accessed again use the files stored locally instead of downloading them once again from the web.

This can be usefull for webApps running on 3G, to reduce the amount of data to download.

However, I'm not sure if those files can be accessed during page load. Anyone know about this?

Comment: what's wrong with caching ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [cache manifest file](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) instead of localStorage

Comment: I implemented the link you suggested from html5Rocks Andreas, however a problem came up: Google Chrome, Safari and IE9+ worked fine, but firefox alerted the user with a message at the top saying my site is requesting offline storage space (for cache, not html5) on his computer. That message also gives him the choice to allow/deny it. This should be transparent to the user ... Any other way to implement it without firefox throwing this message?

Comment: Seems you can"t have both (non alert in ff and cache), but you an prevent storage in ff: https://gist.github.com/bumpux/4567599

Comment: Heads up to anyone who tries this: every now and then I have a few problems where the page is not changing after I changed its code and changed the manifest to force it to reload contents. The best way to solve is refresh the page with Ctrl+F5 as this seems to forces the browser to not use cache.

Answer (score 1):

Generally browsers cache CSS files for you automatically.  Even in mobile.

Answer (score 1):

This *would* be possible however this is quite costly since on pageload you have to manually load the string, convert it to a style/script and insert it into the DOM so it get's recognized by the browser. Also there might be the case that a browser does not support localStorage or the User blocked your access to it.

It's better to set the cache directives accordingly with meta tags and/or cache manifest - also browser will normally cache your files automatically by themselves.